# preventing binding of lvalue references to non-const objects

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to prevent the binding of lvalue references to non-const objects to my function argument, currently I have this code:

```
template <typename T>
using remove_cr = std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>;

template <typename T>
using is_nc_lvalue_reference
  = std::integral_constant<bool,
      std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value
      && !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value
    >;

template <typename T>
void func(T && v, typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_same<THE_TYPE_I_WANT, typename remove_cr<T>::type>::value
  && !is_nc_lvalue_reference<T>::value>::type* = 0)
{
}
```

This seems a tremendous lot of code to me, does there exist a more elegant SFINAE or non-SFINAE method? I don't need perfect forwarding, but if I don't use it, I lose `T`.

The idea is, that `const` objects should not be modified, hence I can convert them to some other representation and feed them, say to a different process. If a non-const reference is given, the object it references can be modified, but the other process does not have access to memory space of the forwarding process and hence I don't forward it.

Comment: Can't you use a `const` reference?

Comment: I don't want to no. They bind everything AFAIK.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. If your lvalue references can't bind to non-`const` objects, then what will they bind to? A non-const lvalue reference can only bind to non-`const` lvalues.

Comment: Looks like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Would you explain why you need a non-const reference that cannot bind to non-const objects?

Comment: to `const` objects, of course and all `rvalue` references, everything but non-`const` references.

Comment: @user1095108 And you're not going to modify the argument inside the function?

Comment: @Angew my problem is `X` and I have asked `X`, I don't know if my `Y` is correct.

Comment: @sftrabbit no, convert it into text, `JSON` and send that away.

Comment: @user1095108 Your problem is something we don't know and you've asked for how to have a reference that accepts `const` lvalues and both non-`const` and `const` rvalues. I cannot see why you wouldn't be okay with a `const` lvalue reference that binds to everything.

Comment: @user1095108: And why can't it be const to be serialized?

Comment: @GManNickG because non-`const` means that you're able to modify, but I am unable to from the other process. The answer is not complete, though, SFINAE will give an error, but the answer won't produce it.

Comment: @user1095108: This makes no sense. Just because you can doesn't mean you have to. Make the parameter type `const T&` and there you go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
template <typename T>
void func(const T &x) {
  process(x);
}

template <typename T>
void func(T &x) {
  do_nothing(x);
}
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/2vgpNd) in action.

Comment: Amazing! How come I don't ever come up with simple solutions like that. `const&` will bind everything and `&` will only bind `&`.